# What exactly is meant by a "ground sense operational amplifier"?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have found this specification in many datasheets, but I have failed to find a good explanation about what exactly is the issue that a ground sense op amp is meant to deal with.

Comment: Google seems to think it means a rail-to-rail input opamp, except for just the ground rail, no both rails.

Comment: Yes, but then rail-to-rail would be redundant, since the op amp does not really know where the ground is. The "best-but-not-really-good" I could find was this: Ground sense opamps can operate up to the ground level of the input signal. I/O full swing types operate from both input/output and ground to the supply voltage, and is also referred to as Rail-to-Rail. Output full swing can provide output from ground to the supply voltage. https://www.rohm.com/products/faq-search/faqId/1570

Comment: No, the term rail-to-rail is not redundant because if you read the term "rail-to-rail" carefully you will realize it is referring to two different rails which means an input or output (or both) can approach both positive and negative rails. Ground sense means it can only approach the ground rail (or negative rail if you want) As for ground, ground often just means reference and as far as the the op-amp is concerned, the negative supply terminal is the ground (or reference) for the entire circuit inside the opamp, which could be different from the ground/reference outside if bipolar supplies.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you meant in your first comment now. I also was on the impression that maybe ground sensing had to do with input, while rail-to-rail had to do with output.

Comment: "Rail-to-rail" on its own is ambiguous as to whether it is input, output or both. Ground sense seems to always mean input though (cannot sense with an output after all).

Comment: A manufacture's definition: "Op amps that allow signals only to the negative rail will be referred to as ground-sensing amplifiers. Those that allow signals to either rail will be referred to as rail-to-rail input amplifiers.", from [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/656.html)

Comment: @jay, nice application note, that's the kind of explanation I was searching for.

Comment: @MarceloRobertoJimenez, Yah I knew it. H h... still, answers are agreeable, down there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be similar meaning to "single-supply" op-amp (eg. LM358) - input range includes the negative rail, and the output can swing fairly close (hundreds of mV) to the negative rail while sinking a bit of current.

[ROHM](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/348/bd77501g_e-1873448.pdf) uses the term:

> Input and output are operable GND sense

It's a translation from Japanese so you have to expect a bit of idiosyncrasy. The important things are the numbers in the datasheet.

On a separate subject, it's a little odd that they would recommend a maximum load capacitance of 0.01 nF (10pF) but mention that it will not oscillate even with a load of several nF (several hundred times higher). Possibly an error.

Comment: Brief and clear explanation, like always.